# Are late answers with invisible PayPal links acceptable?

Tags: discussion, spam, specific-answer

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34837632/1016716) late answer to a question, and I can't even tell if it attempts to answer the question at all.

Anyway, there's an hidden link to PayPal at the end. Is that acceptable?

I don't know if I should just edit to remove the link or if the answer should be deleted.

Other similar answers by the same user (all late answers, not very readable, with lots of formatting and with the same link to PayPal):
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34836907/1016716)<sup>∗</sup>, 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34872401/1016716)<sup>∗</sup>,
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835878/1016716),
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34758866/1016716)<sup>∗</sup> and
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34953602/123527)<sup>∗</sup>.
They have all been edited since, but you can see the original in the edit histories.

<sup>∗</sup> currently deleted; see below

Comment: I don't know either. What I *do* know is that I should probably go and see a doctor right now because I might have caught something from that answer. (And, no, it has nothing to do with their so-called "dark-force ways".)

Comment: It's not the only one with that link. Other questions from the user (such as this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/34953602/123527) contains a link to PayPal.

Comment: I don't think it's *safe* to say that it's a spammer...it seems to be more like the link blends in to the "natural" flow of the answer.  At the same time, the way that they're promoting it *and* their abuse of Unicode ***really*** gives me the heebie-jeebies - not unlike my first exposure to Zalgo.

Comment: They're seeking money from their answers, I'm pretty sure that goes against Stack Exchange terms as they're trying to earn money from something they don't own.

Comment: No, not necessarily.  There are some people that will donate money to others for their answers, but it's more of a faux pas to hold your hand out like that, and Stack Exchange doesn't officially support it.

Comment: If you have a link like that add it to your profile, not as noise in every answer.

Comment: @Makoto By submitting a post to Stack Exchange, you're agreeing that you no longer own the content in the post- Stack Exchange does.

Comment: And if they are accepting money, they should say so in full, with a clear link to their donations page. Not with a link that is glued on at the end of another link and which the user might click by mistake.

Comment: @MrLister:  Please don't misunderstand me.  I ***wholeheartedly*** agree with the sentiment.  I'm simply saying that I can't think of any rule that prevents this in something like their *profile* page, but it definitely doesn't belong in answers.

Comment: @cybermonkey:  [CC-by-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) which is what their post is licensed under, doesn't restrict non-commercial usages, so they are technically permitted to resell the answer if they so choose, so long as they give attribution.  At least, that's my initial reading of it, IANAL.

Comment: @Francesco Menzani I don't like your edit. First, the answers are not "good" by any standard. And, personally I don't give a hoot about the bad formatting. I could have been more descriptive than my original one though; I'll edit again.

Comment: @cybermonkey That is totally incorrect.  You own what you write.  And now (officially), others must attribute what they copy from this site to the OP.

Comment: @BAR SO owns the content when you hit the submit button, not you. Check the licence.

Comment: @cybermonkey https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/  Don't just assume they are like every other company.  This is a big reason SE has become so successful IMO.

Comment: @BAR I'm not assuming like they are every other company, it's been stated in Meta many times that the OP of the post does not own it.

Comment: What are they trying to gain from an invisible PP link I wonder...  New filter in 3, 2, 1...

Comment: @cybermonkey Links?

Comment: @cybermonkey: I have been one of those saying that or something very similar. What I (and hopefully others) mean is simple, but admittedly easy to misinterpret: **once you post on SO, you can't stop editors from doing their duty**, although you can influence them more than others. This does **not** mean you can no longer use your own post content however you like; it just means you're not the exclusive benevolent-dictator-for-life of it any more.

Comment: In a world where SE is the sole owner of all human knowledge and intellectual property ever to exist... at least since 2008.

Comment: And the person's icon is a steal of the Google icon...

Comment: @CindyMeister I would give them the benefit of the doubt and say "inspired by".

Comment: Seems like a filter should be in place for the string `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if one was to follow those links, what would actually happen? Does it take the user to a PayPal donation page? Would it actually initiate a donation if logged in to PayPal if a recent transaction was made? I'm not about to try to find that out myself.

Comment: Anybody have an imgur link to one of these posts for, uh, science?

Comment: @APerson: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AX9FE.png And that's just one of the milder cases. One of the other answers has since been undeleted - you could peek into its revision history at your own peril...

Comment: @MrLister, you could edit your question to add [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996603/should-i-add-both-java-home-and-jre-home-in-environmental-variable-path/34733232#34733232) as an example that was not deleted. [This revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34733232/4) contains the original problem.

Comment: @Zanon Oh, all the posts I mentioned were deleted. This one happened to be undeleted later, after editing by me and others. I marked the deleted ones in the question now.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I don't know either if any of those posts is spam, and I'm not inclined to read through them even though I've got a hazmat suit on.

What I can say is that PayPal links don't belong in answers. Putting it generously, they fall under the same category as "thanks", "hope this helps", and signatures. If a user is accepting donations, they may place a donation link in their profile — doing so is perfectly acceptable.

But not in an answer, because — morality or ethics or legality aside — it's simply not part of the answer's content.

For now, the donation links will be edited out and we'll contact the user about them specifically. The content and formatting of the answers can be discussed separately.

Comment: Got any brain bleach?  The one post I did edit kind of did me in.

Comment: @Makoto: I'm sorry.

Comment: I removed the Paypal links from them now, but I see someone is already deleting all of them.

Comment: @MrLister: that was me, I came to the same conclusion as BoltClock but saw nothing worth saving.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But now the offender may not even have seen the link to this discussion. They won't have learned from this!

Comment: @MrLister: I'll repost the link in a comment; posting as a moderator that makes sure they'll see this.

Comment: Just looked through the OP's last 20 answers or so. Glad to say the paypal link didn't show up except in the two already identified; I stopped at ~20. Emojis and extraneous noise abound, but in the ones I saw, the user *was* trying to answer the question (with varying degrees of success and quality).

Answer (score 65):

Those links are a misplaced attempt at panhandling; *please buy me a coffee* donation links. I've plain deleted the posts; there is *too much work* to be done to them for very little gain.

Stack Overflow should be a collection of quality questions with even better answers, aimed at future visitors who expect to not have to wade through pages upon pages of forum posts that have formatting *just like those posts*. Such wackiness has no place here.

I've dropped the user a line to inform them of my decision, and asked them to refrain both from adding such links and from formatting their posts like this.

Comment: I agree on your decision with regard to the formatting and the link as well as the subsequent warning send to the user. I don't agree with the deletion, the posts were unique and added useful information (at the least the one I was trying to salvage). You might have deleted value.

Comment: @rene: then flag the ones you believe are worth saving. I salute your heroics.

Comment: Challenge accepted, flagged one.

Comment: Thanks for doing this, undeleted.

Comment: [FWIW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996603/should-i-add-both-java-home-and-jre-home-in-environmental-variable-path/34733232#34733232)

Answer (score 20):

Christ, this answering style annoys me.

Now that **that's** out of the way, let's sift through this.

[This is an example of an attempt at an answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835878/1079354)  In spite of the emoji just **in the way**, the answer is at least an *attempt*.  I'm not saying it's *correct*, but it's an attempt.  So, we can't say that this particular answer is a spam answer.

[The same looks to be true of this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34837632/1079354)  Again, the answer *style* is enough to make me want to edit it out, but it is an *attempt* at an answer.

The one common thread is that PayPal link, which definitely needs to go.  That seems to be the main thing everyone is taking umbrage to, and for good reason, since it doesn't add any value to the answer.  I doubt anyone would care if they placed a link to it in their profile, but actively promoting it in answers is both counterproductive to the answer and extremely noisy.

So:

- Edit the emoji out
- Fix the unnecessary formatting decisions
- Remove the occurrence of the link from *every* post and let them know that's something they shouldn't repeat
- Direct them to this post in a constructive fashion so they can at least understand what we're so upset about

Comment: Might also be worthwhile pointing them to services such as [HackHands](https://hackhands.com/) if they want to make money by helping others with programming. They obviously want to make *some* money (otherwise the hidden PayPal link wouldn't be there) so it wouldn't be breaking Stack Overflow's terms/license as it wouldn't be on Stack Exchange.

Comment: My issue is not so much with the donations link as such, but with the fact that they put it in in such a sneaky way, so close to another link! Also, they may look like attempts at answering, but they're all _late answers_, most of them to questions that have long since been solved.

Comment: @MrLister:  There's nothing wrong with a late answer.  There's *everything* morally wrong with the way the link is placed, but I believe that we can reach the OP and correct the behavior on that.

Comment: @MrLister If I'm interpreting you correctly, are you suggesting that they're (poorly) attempting to disguise their donation link by adding *late answers* to questions that haven't been active for a while? If so, they obviously are not aware of the *Late Answers* review queue, which exists primarily to filter out this behavior.

Comment: @cybermonkey:  Given that it's the weekend (which comes with lower traffic) and given the queues' tendency to let things slip, *somehow* I doubt that the queue played its part on this one...