# Our policy on posts with hidden link spam to the author's website

Tags: discussion, spam

We get posts that contain a link to the author's website hidden in some part of the post.

When flagging those as spam (for the missing affiliation), I get mixed responses back as the result, ranging from "declined - Just edit out the link!", to "helpful".

A example of a hidden link to the authors website, can be seen in the following posts:

- > [image]

  This post was linking to `http://jaspreetchahal.org` without disclosing the affiliation of the author

  This post was not deleted and the link has been edited by a moderator

  [SPAM] flag marked "declined"
- > [image]

  This post was linking to `http://giordanomaestro.blogspot.it/2012/12/orgw3cdomdocument-convertion-utils.html` without disclosing the affiliation of the author

  This post was not deleted and the link has been edited by a moderator

  [SPAM] flag marked "helpful"

A few more cases of the hidden link, where the post was also plagiarism:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36542052 (deleted)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36542012 (deleted)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36541912 (deleted)

All three of the above posts followed the same pattern; the OP created an answer, and then included a hidden backlink in the dot to his own website, in order to promote his own website.

**TL;DR:**

What is our policy on these kind of answers (post with hidden backlink) and how should we treat them?

Comment: This is breaking rule 1 in SO's [expected behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), I can not see how this is not a hidden attempt to spam (gain higher ranking on google), not knowing about the "no-follow" rule.

Comment: When a moderator sees that post, all they're going to see is the text. If you've got spam that's "hidden", submit a custom flag that explains why it's spam.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker but then we lose the six flag nuke. It also doesn't solve that some mods think that spam should be edited out instead of deleted.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Unless that moderator then truly spam-nukes it (-100 rep and heavy heuristics bias included) I feel like thats an unacceptable solution. That is spam, and the guy writing it needs treating with the same penaltys as a normal spammer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I also added a comment that explained that there was a hidden link in the post itself, that was missing affiliation for the 2 top cases that where not deleted, they where probable removed by the same moderator as the one who edited it

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, but moderators have a one-flag nuke.  It's not ideal; but it's better than having to complain that your spam flag was declined because a moderator was looking at it from the mod panel and it didn't look like spam there.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'm just waiting forwards for "declined - no need to take this to the mods, a spam-flag would have removed it without our intervention".

Comment: @ChrisF The name of the poster was needed to see to everyone that the author was not disclosing his affiliation with the website he is linking, without this vital key piece of information (linked url contains username of poster), the reason I flagged it as spam is void

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Can mods not see how many flags were cast? If there were more than 1, then it's obviously worth taking an extra minute to examine the source/history. Better yet, let all flags have optional free text to accompany them. You can't nuke a spam post with `other` flags.

Comment: @Rob If we didn't have issues with multiple flaggers getting it wrong because they pile on from a chat room, we could trust multiple flags more; as it is I tend to be suspicious since that is much much much more common than this type of hidden spam is.  That said, we generally take a second or third look in cases where there are a lot of flags and we can't find the issue; but this particular spam seems designed to try to defeat what the moderator sees.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker That makes it even more egregious and even less of an "One time mistake"

Comment: @GeorgeStocker any chance mods could install a userscript to highlight these hidden links?

Comment: @Rob: "You can't nuke a spam post with other flags." If you are flagging a post for non-obvious reasons that require a custom message, then you want a moderator to be making that judgement call, and having the post be nuked automatically before a moderator has had the chance to intervene is the *last* thing you want to happen. (A mod can reverse the outcome after the fact, but as the saying goes, prevention is better than cure.)

Comment: For the record, [I suggested the "linked punctuation" SmokeDetector rule in Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=28884018#28884018) in response to answers linking to the Twitter feed of a foreign politician, which I think we can agree are clearly spam attempts.

Comment: @ChrisF Yep, I'm confused why OP hid the poster's avatar but not his name? and why the poster's personal website and name were included in the description as well? It's simply not the right thing to do, esp. when you consider Meta's propensity for mob upvotes/downvotes (aka meta effect).
Sure the poster made a bad decision but we're not here to point fingers nor play the shame game; that's not what Meta is for.

Comment: IMHO those posts should be deleted. Having the link edited out isn't punishment of any form and spammers (ignoring no-follow for a second) just rely on only some of these to be spotted. SO is truly big enough to not desperately rely on such "contributions". Delete the post, let somebody else answer. Rinse and repeat a few times. Ban the user.

Comment: @IngoBürk - While it's fun to get all torch-and-pitchforks on Meta, I'd rather err on the side of preserving content and giving these users the benefit of the doubt. You'd be surprised at the number of respected members of this community who started out excessively promoting their website or products. If we think there's any hope at all of salvaging a user, we'll warn instead of suspending and give them a chance to reform. The recidivism rate is surprisingly low. Taking a more hard-line approach would have cost us many people who went on to be valuable contributors.

Comment: @BradLarson What exactly are we doubting? That those users don't know that they're hiding link information because they at least suspect that it's fishy? But either way, I didn't suggest banning anyone who does it. I suggested removing their content, letting them know what they did wrong and let them try again. Only if they keep ignoring it, get out the pitchfork.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Is it appropriate to hide a link to your website in a clever link within your post? No. This is frowned upon in the same way that adding a tagline linking back to your site is. In fact, moderators have a template message (infrequently used) for warning people about this:

> Hello,
>
> I'm writing in reference to your Stack Overflow account:
>
> [account]
>
> I noticed that many of your posts include things like signatures, tag
>   lines, or other information that isn't part of your question or
>   answer. I wanted to let you know that we have a place in your profile
>   where you can tell us all about yourself, and it's directly linked
>   from everything you write.
>
> Coming from your traditional discussion forums, I understand that it
>   is often customary to be a bit more cordial and chatty in your posts,
>   but at Stack Exchange, one of our goals is to build a library of
>   high-quality questions and answers where it's as easy as possible to
>   find the best answer. I know this can come across as a bit persnickety
>   — this crazy Q&A site that hates conversation — but it's
>   that "just the answers" ethos that results in over 90% of the
>   questions getting great answers, often stunningly quickly.
>
> I look forward to your future contributions. I hope you'll consider
>   telling us about your interests and what you've been working on in
>   your profile. We actually love to see it there — it gives the
>   community a little color on the real people who share their knowledge
>   here — but we try to keep it out of the main Q&A.

The standard procedure when we find people using taglines with links to their site, but the posts themselves are decent, is to edit out the tagline in each post and send them the above message without a suspension.

The use of taglines with links is far more common than what you describe above (I can count on both hands the number of times I've dealt with hidden links like this), but for established users like the two you highlight above I'd treat them in the same manner as those using taglines. Applying an immediate 100-points spam penalty and IP block for a first-time offense of this seems a bit extreme.

If the only thing they have posted were plagiarized answers with spam links (the three deleted posts you link), that's clearly malicious and I destroyed one of those users because of that. I like to give established users with more to their name the benefit of the doubt and a chance to reform before penalizing them. 100 point penalties coming out of the blue [can be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319021/reputation-cut-down-by-100) [confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313073/why-do-i-now-have-1-reputation-after-posting-a-question) at the least.

I know that some members have found a new thing to hunt down, and people want this dealt with immediately, but I highly recommend using custom flags for this and describing exactly where the link is hidden in the post. If a link is hidden like this, moderators may not see it at a glance with a simple spam flag. We can still apply a hard spam flag and destroy the account if necessary, but we may also decide to edit out the link and warn a user if they otherwise are a good contributor.

Again, it's not appropriate to hide links like this, but more nuanced handling may be required than just targeting posts with spam flags.

Comment: So an other flag(with a good explanation) should have been raised instead?

Comment: @NathanOliver - Yes, that's what I'd prefer. A spam flag carries no context, so you're relying on a moderator to go to the markdown to see the problem. We can still apply a spam flag after the fact if we need to, but if the spam isn't obvious, you run the risk of getting this flag declined. Also, we may want to treat this differently than pure spam for otherwise good users and warn them before penalizing them.

Comment: This eloquently describes my feelings of these being teachable moments for people rather than anonymous punishments for inhuman objects; +1

Comment: Wait, you mean spam is generated by *people* and not inanimate objects?!

Comment: It wasn't the close vote receiver that came up with the punctation in link spam detection, this originated in the CharCoal HQ idea to detect more spam. We took the idea in the Close Vote Receivers to find older posts that failed this rule

Comment: Adding a tagline is something done openly. Inserting a hidden link is a deceptive tactic, something that doesn't square well with "be honest" rule of behavior. I would not equate the two.

Comment: If the flag is marked as helpful does it automatically apply the -100 penalty?  If that is the case the auto-penalty seems problematic and might have to change, because if a flagger doesn't know the details (e.g. the template message) then he would wrongfully get a flag declined.

Comment: -1 I don't really like the sentiment that we should go easy on such clear intentional misuse of the service just because the users doing it are "established users". Its clearly behaviour which is meant to intentionally deceive. What is the point of the 100 rep penalty if its not going to be applied to users who might actually care about it.

Comment: @rdans: Strictly speaking, the 100-point penalty was originally a hack to make sure quick-and-dirty spammers would lose privileges while they were being dealt with, but these days there are better mod tools for dealing with them fast, so it's kind of an orphan.

Comment: So does the spam flag needs is an optional comment box explaining why it is spam?

Comment: Re: your reply to @NathanOliver, are you sure you really want a flag in this situation at all? It seems to me that, at least for users with edit privileges, the right thing to do is to simply remove the link and explain to the user why they shouldn't do that. If the user persists, then I see a reason to flag the post, but otherwise why drag a ♦ into it at all?

Comment: @podiluska the ones I destroyed I would likely have failed to spot without the comment that was added by someone (helpfully) highlighting the issue. I'm alert to the MO now, but it's hard to spot sneaky stuff always given the current SNR on spam flags.

Comment: So, it is win-win for spammer, right (or maybe rather win-zero)? He either sucessfully promoted his link or got no punishment and in no way worse situation than before. Well maybe if post is otherwise useful it is okay to only edit it and not remove, but user still **should be punished in either case**.

Answer (score 21):

Moderators are human. And well, that's a pretty annoying way to hide things that are hard to notice. It's an exceptional situation, and one that might not be noticed at first glance.

This is one of the few cases where I'd suggest custom flagging a spammy link. "The user's hidden a link after the word 'etc' in the second paragraph.

Since these are otherwise useful answer, a moderator can educate the user as necessary.

Comment: It is far too common to be called an exceptional situation...

Comment: @Jan the exceptional is always more common on SO.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I've never come across this before today.

Comment: @ChrisF I may have seen it years ago already, actually.

Comment: Its not common, obvious, spam. Its something that's not obvious unless you knew what to look for. While I'm a relatively small site mod, considering the workload of SO mods, it seems like a better idea than to assume the mods know what to look for. Sadly, our mod hats do not give us psychic powers ;)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You don't have any psychic powers, but you do have a chat room. And a comment under the post _should_ be enough to help you if you (understandably) don't know why a post was flagged.

Comment: I think I've seen this approach to spam **once** previously.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Since smoke detector started reporting it, I've seen 4 today in the chat I was in (and not really paying THAT much attention). Definitely seems fairly common

Comment: @Rob It could be that these instances just started occurring recently.

Comment: I guess when mods realise that feeding these into the "other" bucket isn't the best option, they will speak up to us in the SOCVR room? Until then, I will do as instructed.

Comment: any chance mods could install a userscript to highlight these hidden links?

Comment: @JanDvorak I doubt that'd be effective unless you could get every mod now and forever to install it.

Comment: @TylerH OK, any chance to get the dev team to do anything about the situation?

Comment: @JanDvorak Post on meta :-)

Comment: None of you remember [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315341/are-late-answers-with-invisible-paypal-links-acceptable)? (Whether it's spam is debatable but it's the same tactic of concealing dubious links in inconspicuous parts of a post.)

Comment: If you color the links as red in the review queue this won't happen anymore.

Comment: Blue dot. Red dot. Black dot. Still hard to see.

Comment: Easy, color the background instead of the glyph, and add gratuitous amounts of padding!

Comment: and add a red freehand circle!

Answer (score 19):

Posts that contain hidden links that are unrelated to the content should be marked as spam, because:

- The only purpose of linking unrelated things is to generate back traffic, or to promote your own products.
- According to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263051/is-it-ok-to-edit-obvious-spam-to-break-links), we should not edit out bad links to the authors website

Comment: I am curious about the down votes, which statement do they not agree with?

Comment: So isn't this a dupe of the post you yourself linked in your answer?

Comment: I think editing out the link and leaving a comment the first time, then *custom flagging* the second time is more appropriate than spam flagging. Like TLM said in chat, if a user posts a link to their blog on an otherwise good answer, they may not know they are breaking spam rules. I do think that *hiding* a link is problematic, but we should give users the benefit of the doubt. Also I'm curious if moderators consider eponymous blog links to be "missing affiliation" . If a user Thor Manslayer posts a link to thormanslayer.blogspot.com, it's kind of obvious that it's his blog...

Comment: @TylerH, please add links in your answers to your own blogs (so everybody can vote), but do **not** do this trying to hide your links, because the moment you hide your link, you are on the wrong side breaking the first rule of SO and -100 rep or suspension will do some good.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Like I said, hiding the links is problematic. But it's not for you or me to say that -100 rep or a suspension will "do some good". That's the moderation team's decision.

Comment: @TylerH For me that tells me that you are trying to spam, not good faith anymore, see my first [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320786/our-policy-on-posts-with-hidden-link-spam-to-the-authors-website#comment331953_320786) and its up to the community to find and red flag these attempts.

Comment: @PetterFriberg That falls under the "benefit of the doubt" umbrella that both I and ChrisF have mentioned... the first time, treat it as a learning experience, aka Be Nice (Rule #1). If it happens again, *then* mod-flag it (as opposed to spam flagging because mods don't currently see full context of spam-flag posts in their queue).

Comment: @TylerH, be nice is rule 2, be honest is rule 1, but lets just disagree, when you break rule 1 the "benefit of the doubt" does not apply for me anymore.

Comment: _"Posts that contain hidden links that are unrelated to the content should be marked as spam"_ -- No. Only posts which _are_ spam should be marked as spam. Hiding links is bad, anti-social behavior, but it doesn't constitute "spam" when the post is otherwise a legitimate question or answer on the SO site. Only a post that is _itself_ in its entirety intended as advertisement would be properly considered as "spam". That's not the case here.

Answer (score 8):

I think I can only see two different ways to handle such flags.
They look a lot like the way to handle fishy posts in general:

1. User with legit content:

   Comment, explaining that the behaviour is not [welcomed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) and might look spammy. If consensus can't be reached (for example the user rollbacked an edit that removed such link), use a moderator flag explaining the situation.
   The main point of this strategy is to educate a user without involving a diamond and its precious time, all while destroying fishy content.
2. User without legit content (plagiarized, NAA, various garbage...):

   This user adds no value to SO and should be nuked. Spam flags with a comment on the post(s) indicating the reason for such flags to the diamond reviewer (*`This post contains hidden links in punctuation and is spam[, its content was plagiarized from (source)]`*).
   This allows for quick destruction of useless content and users.

---

Diamond reviewers do not want to penalize users in the first case the same way spammers are penalized, so spam flags should be rejected. In fact, moderators should not be involved unless there is a pattern of abuse that is not easily dealt with by the community (many links to a paywall / other unacceptable content, user rollbacked edits that remove the links, etc).

On the second case however, the user's only contribution was garbage with fishy links.
As goes with common spam, complete and utter destruction should follow.

Comment: So, it is win-win for spammer, right (or maybe rather win-zero)? He either sucessfully promoted his link or got no punishment and in no way worse situation than before. Thanks, but no, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, I [ran an SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/471269/generic-post-content-like-search?PostHTML=%25%22%3E%5B.%2C%5D%3C%2Fa%3E%25&ExcludeHTML=%3Cnothing%3E&MaxResults=100&StartDate=2016-03-01&EndDate=2016-04-15) to look for posts on SO with links having only a single period or comma as the link text, and found and mod-flagged a couple dozen of them.

> [image: Screenshot of pending mod flags]
> <sup>(Click image to enlarge.  Usernames and link URLs blurred to avoid needless "naming and shaming", although obviously it's not hard to dig up the actual posts if one wants to.)</sup>

There were a few false positives, including what seemed to be honest editing mistakes (i.e. valid and relevant pages linked from a single period instead of the preceding word) and a couple of seemingly harmless "easter egg" links to funny and tangentially relevant pages.  Especially among older posts, I also found several instances of users linking to other relevant SO posts like this, presumably to make them show up in the "linked questions" sidebar without creating an actual visible link in the post text.  I don't think that's something we should be encouraging (usually, if something's worth linking at all, it's worth linking properly), but it's not spam.

More disconcertingly, however, I also found one 50k+ rep user who has been editing hidden links to their Android game on Google Play Store into their highest-voted posts (where they're [exempt from rel=nofollow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209309/what-is-the-threshold-for-removing-rel-nofollow-from-links-in-posts)), and another 2k+ user who's been doing the same with their company website.  In both cases, I noticed the pattern after the second post I found from the same user, and described it in my mod flags.  Since those flags are still pending, I have no idea how the mods will handle those cases.  Personally, I certainly don't think something like an accepted answer with 100+ score should be deleted as spam, but I *would* expect at least the hidden links to be removed and the user told not to do it any more.

Ps. I also ran the same query on several other large SE sites, but only found a couple of actually dubious links.  It seems that SO, besides obviously having the largest post volume, is also the most tempting target to spammers due (presumably) to its high Google ranking, large number of mirrors and the ease of slipping such sneaky posts into the huge volume of incoming content.

I also tried to look for other characters like apostrophes that might be used for making near-invisible links, but the only actual spam links I found were all using either periods or (very occasionally) commas.  Unfortunately, the search method I'm using (which is based on an SQL `LIKE` query on the post HTML) is not as flexible or reliable as I'd really like, so I might be missing some variations.  In particular, I can't easily search for spam links with *completely empty* link text, since my query can't tell image links from empty ones (except by excluding *all* posts with images from the results).

---

**Update:** Since writing this, all my flags have now been processed, and all the flagged posts (except, for some weird reason, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353785/facebook-login-is-blinking/4357569#4357569)) have been either deleted or (for the posts by the two high-rep users mentioned above) edited to remove the spam links.  I believe this is a reasonable outcome, and I don't think the users whose posts were edited will try to do this again (especially given that the ♦ mod who made the edits also left each of them a comment calling them out on it).

No new hidden-link spam posts seem to have appeared on SO since this answer was written — or, if some did, they've presumably been rapidly dealt with, now that people (and our spam detector bots) are aware of the issue.

Comment: It seems that there are also people who use ? as special punctuation characters, but those are usually help links

Answer (score -3):

This kind of thing is hardly worth flagging as spam for a post that mostly is relevant, answers the question, and is fair quality.

To expand on that - a post of that quality is a good answer. It's only fault is to have a link which may or may not be relevant, but is to the author's own blog.

Marking that as spam is heavy handed - while I agree that it's not entirely legit to hide the link, all that really needs to happen is someone to edit it out and tell the poster not to do it again.

If they do it again, a mod flag is warranted, perhaps accompanied by a spam flag. Not before.

That said, for the mods - if someone flagged this as spam on my site, I would mark the spam flags helpful without applying a penalty. It's been flagged in good faith and has drawn attention to a post that needs action taken on it, so it has been helpful in doing the job.

Comment: Its an unsolicited advertisement to something unrelated, specifically masked as to not reveal its purpose, to gain search ranking. Why would that not be spam?

Comment: I like it but how do we know if they do it again?  One should not "stalk" a user so if they do this in a couple answer and we fix it how do we make sure the user does not keep doing it?  Shouldn't an other flag been raised and the mods can communicate to and keep track of the user?

Comment: `If they do it again, a mod flag is warranted, perhaps accompanied by a spam flag. Not before.` That should be on the mods, not us. They have the tools to do that, not us (at least not to the same extent). Perhaps mods should have the ability to apply the penalty when accepting spam flags, but not have it done always.

Comment: [The spam flag is designed to eliminate posts with no relevant content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/194636) (SE FAQ)

Comment: @Magisch the link itself is spam, no question. But the majority of the rest of the post is good quality enough that it's worth just editing it out to salvage the rest of the post, the "relevant content" as the FAQ says.

Comment: @PaulWhite so if I post a barebones answer and append a ton of unrelated advertising, I bear no risk of penalty because the correct approach is to just edit out the advertising?

Comment: @Jan yes, unless you do it over and over again after being asked not to. Then it should be nuked and penalties.

Comment: @jan plagiarism is a separate reason to flag, separate from whether or not it's spam. If it's plagiarised, then flag it. If it's not but it has a self link, edit it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode excellent. By the way, would you check out [my new car], [this excellent toaster] I'm totally not affiliated with, one of those [tasty, tasty snacks with -10 calories] or perhaps a new [FDA approved p3n15 enlargement spray]?

Comment: @Jan that's irrelevant content, and spam. But if a post has relevant content, reduce it down to only that which is relevant, removing the spammy link. Win win, we get a good answer without spam.

Comment: @ArtOfCode the relevant content in my answer is "excellent". You are free to edit my comment down to just that, I have still earned some visibility to these great products and it didn't harm me in any way.

Comment: @Jan no, one word is not relevant. Ever. And given the editing speed of the ninjas in SOCVR when powered by smokey reports, the ten seconds it's there for are hardly a concern.

Comment: @JanDvorak The spam flag is a high-priority flag with potentially severe consequences for the author. If there's any question that the post is actually *spam*, a different (maybe custom) flag should be used to avoid disappointment.

Comment: @ArtOfCode it might be ten seconds the first time but if they decide to rollback, we have a problem.

Comment: @Jan at *that* point it becomes spammy, and a matter for a mod flag and a spam flag. Not the first time round.

Comment: @PaulWhite there would be no question if mods could see comments when handling the flags, or better yet if an explanation could be provided in the flag dialog...

Comment: @Jan that's a separate feature request, but with the current state of the tools, this is how it is.

Comment: @ArtOfCode it's a separat feature request, and until it gets _any_ attention from the dev team, I don't really feel like flagging spam anymore...

Comment: @Jan your loss. This is only one type of spam, though, there's plenty more. Besides, what percentage of your flags is this *really* affecting? 1? 0.1?

Comment: 10% is already enough to cause me a really annoying udismissable message for a week (happened to me more than once), and once I hit 25% (happened to multiple people in the tavern) I won't be measuring a week until I can start treading the minefield again.

Comment: @JanDvorak If you want to provide additional information, reasoning, or context, use a custom (other...) flag. The handling moderator can always flag it as spam if the consequences of that flag are required.