# Suggested Edits: What Do You Mean This Was Spam?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I can't honestly tell if this was an "audit" or not, but if it is, it really shouldn't be. I got onto the Suggested Edits review queue today and saw...

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11957533 Come back in
>   4 days to continue reviewing.

The problem is, that [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11957533) that I (and several other people) approved was a legitimate formatting improvement on a C++ question, but the system seems convinced that it's spam.

Can someone please explain to me what went wrong? I've had no indication from the system over the past three days of reviewing that I failed any audits, so this message was a complete surprise to me.

Comment: It appears there is an on-going edit-war of-sorts over this: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5124769/revisions

Comment: _"but the system seems convinced that it's spam."_ How did you get this actually??

Comment: While not very common, the indentation style used is a slight variation on the [GNU style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#GNU_style). I suspect these edits may be a crusade against this style or for some other style.

Comment: The note at the top: "This may be spam. Review carefully." However, it cites an "approve" as "incorrect," despite consensus.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, meh, I'm more an Allman-style person myself. I was looking at the indentation. And anyhow, it hit the review queue. Given the information I was presented, I could not POSSIBLY know there was an edit war, or that approving a change that looked fine to me would get me review-suspended. >.>

Comment: If it was an audit, you wouldn't have been banned _now._ A mod banned you manually, because the mod feels that you (and the other reviewers for that review) reviewed incorrectly and approved a harmful edit. In general, edits should not be made just to change the indentation or personal style choices (given that those style choices do not make the post incredibly hard to read.) which is why your approval of that edit was incorrect.

Comment: @Kendra, grah, well, that would make sense. However, I think said mod forgot that things show up in review queue without the context to indicate an edit war. I've been edit reviewing for quite some time (look at my history), and I've gotten it down to a near automatic process with pretty good accuracy. I can't check *every single edit* manually for a dispute.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Sorry, I edited to address _why_ it was wrong, without needing the context of an edit war. Hit the enter button too soon is all.

Comment: Round two: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265571/approved-suggested-edit-from-a-known-troll

Comment: The real question seems to be why people including moderators are trying to rollback changes approved by the OP aka community edits...

Comment: And I see that the question still receives new edits right now. Have we learned nothing? Oh well, at least this last one changes something non-trivial in the code.

Comment: @TylerH: Suggested edits attributed to Community are *made* by anonymous users. Suggested edits *approved* by Community are those *accepted* by the OP. Here we have the former. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work

Comment: @Matt Oh, the Revisions page is a little unclear there

Comment: The story continues: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11990472

Comment: @honk, it looks like a similar issue. The problems would be (a) its an anonymous user edit, (b) 'color' changed to 'colour', and (c) bracket change. The good things, some capitalization and indentation fixed. We **really** need anonymous edits to come with a warning label for the many reviewers that don't know the rules yet.  >.>

Comment: It's the same post, maybe the troll in question now tries to be smarter. At least changing from AE to BE and changing the position of { makes no sense...

Comment: @honk, aih, not sure how I missed that it was *the same post*. (Had I seen that new edit now, I'd have rejected it anyhow.)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Does look like an edit war. But what is concerning about it is that there appears to be a disagreement between a few moderators on one side and a large number of reviewers on the other side. Most of those edits were unanimously approved by reviewers and still reverted by a moderator.

Comment: @kasperd You only see the times it was approved in the edit history, it has been rejected a lot, the troll keeps proposing the edit, and sometimes gets lucky.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara If each of those suggested edits were of identical quality, then each vote should have been independent. Hence the expectation would be to see a distribution centered around the percentage of reviewers who would approve. Of those I would of course only see those with enough approval votes. But that does mean I should have seen a majority of them close to the threshold for rejection and only a minority of them being approved unanimously. I do not know what the reason for this discrepancy is. And I cannot check it, because I don't know how to find *all* the rejected edits.

Comment: @kasperd Here's the list: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-suggested-edits#order=desc&sort=creation&ids=5124769&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Is there a way to get the vote counts other than going through each review manually?

Comment: @kasperd Probably, but I don't know much about SEDE, I just found that query on Google.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It wasn't an audit but, as someone has already pointed out, part of a long term troll of one user by another.

If someone - particularly an anonymous someone - suggests edits that are nothing more than **changing** the formatting of perfectly well formatted code then you need to be rejecting the edit NOT approving it.

This subject came up on Meta Stack Exchange a while ago:

[Editing to change someone's brackets style?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133224/is-it-rude-to-change-someones-brackets-style)

> That said, if doing so helps you trim down a code block so that it can be read without scrolling... **AND you're making [other substantial improvements](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/)** at the same time (indentation, formatting, grammar, tags, etc.)... Then go ahead.

My emphasis.

You should have been paying more attention to both the substance of the edit and who is making the edit. If anything edits from anonymous users should be treated with **more** suspicion and subject to **more** scrutiny than edits by regular users.

**NOTE:** I'm not saying anything about the length of the ban because I don't know for certain who imposed and and I don't want to put words into their mouth. Bans are often the only means we have to make people stop doing what ever it is we don't want them to do and as such are rather crude. Once the issue has been address bans can (and often are) lifted rather than being allowed to expire.

Comment: I understand, but at the same time, nothing in the documentation indicates this. It is pretty common to edit questions to fix code indentation, so others can read. I'm dyslexic - without good indentation, I can't read the code *at all*. I saw indentations added where there were none. If this is the new policy (or the old one), it needs to be clearly stated somewhere, because this just feels like a gotcha.

Comment: @JasonMc92 - Fix code indentation yes, but not change one perfectly valid style to another. In the same way that you don't approve edits that just change British spellings to American ones (or vice versa)

Comment: Is the presence of two unnecessary lines of whitespace atop a four-line codeblock considered stylistically valid? I'd have edited to remove that, too, if I noticed it. It'd be easy to overlook that the bracket moved, because the rest of the changes seem to fix valid formatting issues.

Comment: The way it registered to my eyes, there were no indentations before. I can see them now (barely). Anyhow, there was also excessive vertical space. The bracketing, I couldn't care less what way someone wants it, and I won't approve JUST for that.

Comment: @sphanley - I'd perhaps allow the removal of blank lines, but not the moving of the opening bracket to the line above, but only if they were part of a more comprehensive edit to the post. These were the only changes - as such they were unnecessary,

Comment: @JasonMc92 You might find [this FAQ post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) relevant. One of the examples even addresses style changes.

Comment: @sphanley Some style guides do require 1 empty new line. I'm not sure 2 makes that much difference.

Comment: The point is, I don't care what style someone likes. They can use whatever, and I'll leave it alone. It looked **mis-formatted** to me before, and like it had *one of many valid formats* afterwards. I just figured the moving bracket was force-of-habit while fixing the indentation and extra whitespace problems. The second looked more readable. I'll try and be more careful in the future, however, a 4-day ban on a productive reviewer with good history over something this pedantic seems overkill by any standard.

Comment: @JasonMc92 - If the suggested edit had come from a logged in user I might be inclined to agree with you. However, it came from an anonymous user. The point of my answer is that you **have** to treat those more carefully as we've got no audit trail to see who's doing what.

Comment: @Kendra: Thanks, but that's all stuff I knew. Again, I approved because of *indentation* and *remove excess whitespace*. The bracket was a non-issue for me, and I just assumed that the person put it up there K&D style because that was their instinctual habit.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Just as a note, if you look at the "rendered output" view of the edit in question, it's quite clear that it's a pointless edit that really isn't worth reviewer time, does nothing to improve the post, and should therefore be rejected. In markdown view, it can be hard to tell if the code really _is_ mis-formatted or not. (Personally, I believe you on just making a small mistake. This is more just a tip, if anything. It doesn't take long to switch views, and then you can be even more accurate, and hopefully avoid another small mistake like this in the future.)

Comment: @ChrisF, noted for the future. I still disagree with the four-day ban, unless you can show me where in the review-queue documentation is says to beware of that.

Comment: @JasonMc92 - it's probably not documented as we (the royal "we" that is) didn't think of this scenario.

Comment: @Kendra, I WAS looking at rendered view. The main thing was the vertical whitespace.

Comment: @ChrisF, so, it still comes across as a "you missed a hidden rule! time out for you." It's a good way to drive off productive, good reviewers, nothing personal against you. If I can expect these sorts of surprises, I'd be more inclined to avoid the review queue at all. I don't mind the warning and tips, just the penalty for breaking the unspoken rule.

Comment: @JasonMc92 - Fair point. It wasn't meant that way. I'm not sure where this needs to be written down though.

Comment: Well, I believe a page not unlike our Welcome FAQ for the reviewing area would be in order - your access is blocked until you scroll through it. Then, someone can also click back to see it again. Just having a note there that says "be extra careful of anonymous editors."

Another possible solution would be a warning label not unlike the "possible spam" one - "This review was done by an anonymous reviewer. Please only accept if it improves the question significantly."

Comment: @JasonMc92 I understand your frustration with being banned for the "hidden rule" thing but it happened to me in the past and it taught me to be more careful on those types of posts as Chris has pointed out in this answer. Frustrating? Sure. Worth changing procedures? Probably not. Take a break for a few days then come back to it as I did. Just my 5 cents

Comment: My personality: I'm not likely to come back with that type of policy in place, because I don't know where the other inevitable surprises are. I hate surprise rules, and knowing there are more there that I could never anticipate rather effectively dissuades me from further efforts - it makes the effort high-stress. Surprise *warnings* are productive, and I have no problem learning from those. Surprise *consequences* for breaking the unspoken rule? Nope^2.

Comment: That said, I'm not expecting the system to be perfect. Just knowing that someone will intervene if I'm on the business end of a spring trap like this mitigates the risk. But if those "surprises" are allowed to stand once someone with authority knows they're there, that's when I bail out of the situation. I hope that doesn't sound petty - I just have enough stress as a manager, and I don't need more here. As of right now, the jury's still out.

Comment: @JasonMc92 While Chris' points in this answer stand - it looks like various bans were put in place to mitigate an on-going problem today. I don't believe the review length was made to be sat out, but more that it got reviewers' attention (and I guess 4 days is likely long enough to make sure that if someone comes back - they're going to see it). As that definitely appears to be the case and your review history is good - we've discussed among ourselves and lifted your ban. Sorry for the inconvenience and happy reviewing!

Comment: Thanks @JonClements, my faith in humanity is restored :) I'll be wary of anonymous users. Suggested solution: since this appears to be an ongoing "surprise" for reviewers (link in question comments), perhaps Anonymous User posts need to either be held out of the common queue altogether, or a huge warning label should be slapped on it, so users know those are "special".

Comment: On a side note, this anonymous users keeps trying to make the edit. Is there a way to lock the post from anonymous edits?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - no. The only way is to lock the post totally which will prevent votes, something the troll would regard as success.

Comment: @ChrisF - Do most anonymous users make decent edits?

Comment: Of course that doesn't apply to Python…

Answer (score 6):

I think that the message is VERY misleading. On SO, the term "spam" has a different meaning (in the flag menu at least). It only applies to solicitations that fail to mention the author's affiliation. There's no way that the edit should be considered spam under that definition (a coding style is not a product or service, after all).

When I looked at the edit, because of the recent meta post about hidden spam (the punctuation is a spam link[!!!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320786/our-policy-on-posts-with-hidden-link-spam-to-the-authors-website)), I was looking for a single character to have been changed. And I was confused.

While it's not entirely excusable to miss what ChrisF pointed out (an anonymous troll changing the code style), I found the message VERY distracting (it was essentially a red herring) and it's understandable that you missed the relevant details (anonymous user, changes only in code).

I think the reason for the ban is that the troll already had their SO account suspended for attacking this one user's formatting, and is now making the same edits anonymously. The mods are fed up. Clearly we need better tools to deal with this type of thing.

---

I feel that the change in spacing made it more readable (indentation is always fair game unless it's Python), but when I make similar edits, I always respect the `{` placement. Fortunately(?), these posts seem to always have more issues that need to be fixed, even if it's just tags.

The best solution, with the system as it is, would be to revert the coding style without losing the improved spacing.

Comment: The "This may be spam" message is automated- I don't remember what exactly triggers it, but I think (could be wrong) part of the trigger is the fact that it comes from an anonymous user. It doesn't mean the edit _is_ spam, just that it _may be_ so the edit should be reviewed extra carefully, just in case. While it was wrong in this case, it was more supposed to be a "hey, check this one extra careful, please" than an actual "this edit is totally spam and should definitely be refused" label- If it was the latter, why wouldn't the edit already have been rejected, after all?

Comment: @Kendra Instead of having a poor error message, it should describe *why* the edit is suspicious. Highlighting the fact that the user is anonymous and/or recent activity from the IP was rejected would be magnitudes better.

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying that the wording couldn't be better- It most definitely could. Just pointing out that the whole point of the message (and part of what it literally says) is you should review the suggestion carefully.