# Telltales edited out of audit

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Today I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13834308), I said it "looks OK" based on the fact that it appeared to be a potential solution to OP's question. I agree that the answer is not the best out there, as it is basically code-only answer but that [isn't a reason to blindly delete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262695/new-answer-deletion-option-code-only-answer) it.

Based on the comments under the answer I realized that there used to be some link in the answer that made it spam. But the answer was edited removing this link and making it into the answer I reviewed (and removing the telltale that made it spam).

**So I would like to know, was I wrong to say "Looks OK" for this post?** I get the feeling that for the content I saw it was actually an acceptable review, but that it was considered wrong due to the answers history.

(And as a small secondary question, if spam is edited out, is the answer still considered spam?)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yeah, that was unnecessarily confusing. You weren't the only one to fail an audit based on that post.

I've rolled the edit back and spam-deleted the answer now.

Comment: That's good to know, will this still count as a failed audit? P.S. please don't remove the review ban, I might even get some work done while that is in place ;)

Comment: @B8vrede - I lifted your ban, due to the circumstances here.

Comment: That answer had a lot of issues and concerns if it was spam or not. That looked like salutations at the end. Good to know that the answer was deleted as spam (though I was wrong). Thanks.

Comment: FI: I edited that post since it was not a copy of another post and it seemed like a reasonable answer without the links, moderators have [declined spam flags](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yzpFr.png) on similar answers that ends with links and I'm sure there is a meta somewhere that says to edit out the link, benefit of doubt that OP is only signing his post

Comment: Yeah, I'm not faulting you @Petter. It is *entirely* possible that the author was just attempting to use, a signature, his employer's website. Of course, he probably should've *stopped* doing that after you told him to... If he had, we might not be talking about this now.

Comment: To complete the information it was decided that he was spamming when he post a second answer with same links in a new answer ignoring comment on previous and consequently this answer was deleted by 20K users. This is complete transcript of [actions taken by me in SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=32797383#32797383)

Comment: I would appreciate an indication on how we should handle this in the future.

Comment: @PetterFriberg - In general, don't edit things that have been flagged as spam. It causes problems with audits on spam-flag-deleted posts and can inhibit future searches by moderators to detect spam patterns. There are only a few cases where edits might be appropriate, and that's usually best handled by moderators who can see the whole picture on a user or network. For example, some users post good content but keep trying to link it back to their personal blog, and I'll remove the blog references to keep posts that have demonstrated value. However, usually I'll just delete.

Comment: @Brad, however I can not know if flagged or not, I see only answer and can only judge if it has sense or no sense (without links) and then take actions on "spam" links under answer.

Comment: @Brad this was the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320804/5292302) that I had in mind when editing, spam flags where denied by moderators (spam links in dots, which seems even worse)

Comment: @PetterFriberg - That Meta post refers to taglines (I don't qualify these random commercial links at the end of a post as that) on otherwise quality posts by established users, and the edits I was referring to were by moderators. The posts we're talking about here weren't exactly quality ones, were posted by a brand-new user, and the spammy links don't qualify to me as a tagline. The spam flags were declined in that post because the links were hidden from view, and we weren't given the context that they were there. That's a different issue.

Comment: @Brad I wish not to argue, but decline comment was "just edit out links"  I'm more interested if the conclusion is to spam flag what we judge as low quality post by new users if they contain commercial links under post, hence do not edit it out.

Comment: @BradLarson, I'm curious why linking to a personal blog post that explains the matter further would not be okay.  Wouldn't that be fine as long as affiliation were disclosed?  Which I think would just be, "I wrote a longer blog post on this subject, which you can read here (link).  The brief answer is... etc. etc."