# Why is this LQP Review Audit "Spam or Offensive?"

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24772819) in the LQP Review Queue. So, being a concientious reviewer, I clicked on the "link" to see if it was a 'copy' (or close to one) of any of the other 5 answers ... only to discover that it was an audit (already deleted).

So I duly "Recommended Deletion" and passed the test.

But I'm curious about the given reason for deletion: **"It was flagged as spam or offensive content and deleted 14 days ago by Community♦."** I can see nothing 'offensive' in the post, nor does it contain any link (spam or otherwise).

Am I missing something? Or is it a trick question?

Comment: [Related different case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335500/7296893)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot for the non-10k users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Little digging shows a link got edited out by a moderator before it was deleted, and the user posting this post has *Founder of <same link URL>* in his profile.

Looks like spam to me, for the audit it's unfortunate the link had been edited out before.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! (I guess only 10K+ folks can do the sort of 'digging' you mention.) But, IMHO, it makes for a bad audit because - unless a reviewer checks the link (as I did) - there's nothing there that makes it, in itself, as presented, an LQP.

Comment: Yup, this is a terrible audit (and [someone failed it too](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24660612)), which is one of the reasons we should not edit out spam links. I don't know why the moderator in question decided to do so.